# Multiplatform script

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a .net core app. To setup it i need to run commamds:

```
dotnet restore
bower install
npm install
dotnet build
grunt
```

In visual studio, there is no problem - install & restore commmands are executed automatically and grunt command is bound to "After build" binding.

But what if I want to run all these from command line? Is there any cross-platfrom script engine that I can use? Or need I to prepare two versions: for bash and powershell scripts that run commands shown above?

One way is to use python - but unfortunately runtime must be installed first. Has a dotnet some solution to this problem?

Comment: Assuming you have those tools installed, a bash and a bat script to run them should be identical.

Comment: @TZHX agree, but still - I need to maintain two files (bash and powershell script). If no any solution is available - I will create two files. But just wondering if there exists any alternativie.

Comment: Why introduce powershell into it?

Comment: @TZHX to run these commands on windows.

Comment: Again, why use powershell? Why not just a command/bat script?

Comment: Will bat script run on linux? I'm just looking a way to maintain one script for both: windows and linux.

Comment: If the commands are the same, the Linux doesn't care what you call a file. You just invoke it on the command line with something like `. build.bat`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense ;)

Comment: @TZHX it won't work. Bat file need to contain CALL every line, that is not supported in bash.

Comment: Powershell is now open source. It can run both on linux and windows.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/

Comment: While it might not be ready yet for production machines, PowerShell 6 is an open source project. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell that will also run on Linux and Mac.

Comment: @pwas I don't know where you're getting that information from. I have literally hundreds of .bat scripts that don't use "call". "call" is for when you're calling **other bat scripts**, not commands.

Comment: @TZHX practical test - without `CALL` only first command was called and then - script ended.

Comment: @pwas hmm.. very odd, seems to depend on specific commands (or more likely, how they are implemented). `npm install` won't pass control back, but the `dotnet` ones do and continue to execute the next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project.json you can declare scripts to run during precompile/postcompile

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts

So you could do something like this:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "precompile": ["npm install", "bower install"],
        "postcompile" : "grunt"
    }
}
```

when you run dotnet build it will run npm/bower and then after it builds it will run grunt.